# code syntax auto interpret into html entity code

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I run a php file on my server, it was fine when i edited the code locally. After I uploaded it to the server, some symbols were converted to HTML Entity Code.

Why would this happen?

I'm using Insert_PHP plugin, and the code is running within a page inside Wordpress. I created a few pages, only this is having syntax interpretation issues.

[image: Became html entity code]

Comment: write your code which you try